# iOS Swift 3 - Clearing the UIView

Tags: ios, swift3

I'm building an iOS app where I have a class named "DrawableCanvas" that extends `UIView`. The idea is to enable users to draw on UIViews in the Storyboard that extend the class I made.

The drawing works fine and smooth at this point. Here's the code I used:

```
class DrawableView: UIView {

    let path=UIBezierPath()
    var previousPoint:CGPoint
    var lineWidth:CGFloat=1.0

    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        previousPoint=CGPoint.zero
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let panGestureRecognizer=UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
        panGestureRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches=1

        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.stroke()
        path.lineWidth=lineWidth
    }

    func pan(panGestureRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer)->Void{
        let currentPoint=panGestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
        let midPoint=self.midPoint(p0: previousPoint, p1: currentPoint)


        if panGestureRecognizer.state == .began{
            path.move(to: currentPoint)
        }
        else if panGestureRecognizer.state == .changed{
            path.addQuadCurve(to: midPoint,controlPoint: previousPoint)
        }

        previousPoint=currentPoint
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func midPoint(p0:CGPoint, p1:CGPoint)->CGPoint{
        let x=(p0.x+p1.x)/2
        let y=(p0.y+p1.y)/2
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
    }
}
```

Of course, I have to clear the view on a button press, and here's my button press action:

```
@IBAction func reset1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("reset hit!")
    sig1View.setNeedsLayout()
    sig1View.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

where `sig1View` is the view I'm trying to reset.

This didn't work out, so what I tried instead was to write a `reloadData()` in the `DrawableView` class:

```
func reloadData() {
    print("reload data hit")
    self.setNeedsDisplay()

}
```

The function got called, but that too, didn't work.  How do I clear or reset a UIView in iOS Swift 3?

Comment: Could you make a call to `for layer in view.layers.sublayers { layer.removeFromSuperlayer() } ` I don't have much experience with drawing paths, but that's what I would try first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your `DrawableView`'s (instance's) `path.removeAllPoints` function to remove all the drawings/path.

So following your code, `reset1` should look like this now:

```
@IBAction func reset1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    print("reset hit!")
    sig1View.path.removeAllPoints()
    sig1View.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, although your question *talks* about "resetting", your *code* does not in fact reset anything. You are saying:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    UIColor.black.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
    path.lineWidth=lineWidth
}
```

So that's what's happening. As long as `path` contains a drawable path, that is what is drawn in your view whenever the view redraws itself. If that's not what you want, change the `path`, or change the implementation of `draw`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to DrawableView class and call it with sig1View instance:

```
func clear()
{
    path.removeAllPoints()
    setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

and call it from the reset method.

Usage:

```
sig1View.clear()
```